# Android Camera width and height dependent on orientation?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Does camera width and height in Camera.Parameters change when we change orientation from portrait to landscape ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about the preview width and height then yes it depends on the orientation. Although I don't think it changes on its own. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewSize(int, int))

If you are asking about the image that needs to be captured then no orientation should not have any effect on the width and the height.